# JQuery Performance - Bind event on creation or after placing into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have been trying to convert my web application to use more vanillaJS instead of JQuery for rendering, but due to dependencies on Kendo UI, I have to use JQuery for event binding.

My question is, is it more performant to bind to the element after I have rendered it into the DOM or before?

For example:

```
const element = document.createElement("button")

$(element).kendoButton() //bind

parentElement.appendChild(element)
```

or

```
const element = document.createElement("button")

parentElement.appendChild(element)

$(element).kendoButton() //bind
```

Comment: It will make no significant difference, if any difference at all. Honestly the best way to do event binding is to use jQuery delegation, which will dispense with per-element event handler binding entirely.

Comment: @Pointy `kendoButton()` isn't an event binding, it's a widget initialization. That's not so easy to turn into delegation.

Comment: Writing to the DOM is slow. Its a total guess but i could imagine that creating the "kendoButton" and then attaching it to the DOM is faster. But it's just a guess.
You could do some perfomance measuring yourself with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now
You should then in your script also interact with the button, cause we want to measure from creation till potential interaction.

Comment: @Pointy Gotcha, thanks for the input. I have recently noticed the performance impact of using vanilla JS when rendering, but since I have to create a jquery element in-order to bind my events that sways the render time.

Comment: I understand not wanting to have a jQuery dependency. I feel the same way in that I would like my projects to be as lean as possible. However, what I have found is that it is much easier to maintain a project if you use 100% jQuery or 100% vanilla JavaScript. Since you need the jQuery dependency for the Kendo-UI library, you might as well leverage jQuery rather than piecemealing vanilla JavaScript here and there.

Comment: @David Ill use jQuery where its pretty much needed, but its hard to stay with it, when jQuery themselves recommend using Vanilla JS to boost performance (https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/)

Comment: Like I told you, I personally try to stay away from jQuery because we're in 2022 not 2010. But when I have a client that uses Kendo-UI then I personally would use jQuery throughout the project so that it is easier to maintain. If you want to try and mix and match, then you're only asking for headaches.